# json_encode variable inside array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I am using json_encode to create an array from a foreach that I would like to place inside of a static array. I have loaded the json_encoded array into a variable. If I echo the variable, the data looks great. It's just when I enter the variable into the array, it doesn't work.

This is my foreach.

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($response->records as $record) {
    $r['id'] = $record->Id;
    $r['title'] = $record->Title;
    $r['pin'] = $record->Pin;

$arr[] = $r;

}

$locations = json_encode($arr);
```

And this is my static array where I have entered the $locations variable.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => Locations,
    'data' => '{
        "title":"USA",
        "location":"World",
        "levels":[
            {
                "id":"states",
                "title":"States",
                "locations":'$locations'
            }
        ]
    }'
);
```

This it the error that I am seeing.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$locations' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')'
```

I would appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gizmo you're looking for is the [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) which looks like this

```
.
```

It glues strings together.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => Locations,
    'data' => '{
        "title":"USA",
        "location":"World",
        "levels":[
            {
                "id":"states",
                "title":"States",
                "locations":' . $locations . '
            }
        ]
    }'
);
```

Comment: I noticed what you just mentioned before, I should've changed that in my example. I'll edit that, and the new error I get after changing it but my question is about how to put that $locations into the $data = array().

Comment: That did it! Thank you. I've concatenated strings and variables together before, but I'm not sure I understand why we put one of the operators before and after the variable this time.

Comment: `'data' => '{ "locations":' . $locations . '}';` The whitespace just makes it look funny.

Answer (score 0):

If ı true understood your think, encode the $locations variable to JsonString

```
json_encode($locations)
```

before add $data['data'] elm.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => Locations,
    'data' => '{
        "title":"USA",
        "location":"World",
        "levels":[
            {
                "id":"states",
                "title":"States",
                "locations":' . json_encode($locations) . '
            }
        ]
    }'
);
```